# Activity.finish() called in library, but activity never closes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bluetooth

I'm using this library https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary to get around all of the woes regarding Bluetooth on Android 4.2.x. Which works brilliantly. However, I'm using the inbuilt DeviceList activity to select the device to connect to.

Upon selecting a device the library calls this:

```
    // The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
            if(mBtAdapter.isDiscovering())
                mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            String strNoFound = getIntent().getStringExtra("no_devices_found");
            if(strNoFound == null) 
                strNoFound = "No devices found";
            if(!((TextView) v).getText().toString().equals(strNoFound)) {
                // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
                String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
                String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

                // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(BluetoothState.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

                // Set result and finish this Activity
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                DeviceList.this.finish();   
            }                 
        }
    };
```

Which then returns back to my applications activity which created the intent. Which is all lovely! However, the DeviceList activity never closes, thus I'm left with it at the forefront, which doesn't really help as I'm to show data on the activity I created.

I've adjusted the code slightly, by adding an `onBackPressed`, which again will `finish()` the activity, but you have to press back twice and in very quick succession, which seems really odd, as you can see, it's nothing out of the ordinary:

```
    public void onBackPressed(){
        finish();
    }
```

I've tried almost all of the answers I've found via SO search, including replacing `.finish` with a fully qualified class name (see above @ DeviceList.this.finish()) - I'm also aware that calling finish only really requests that the activity can be closed and the OS will take over from there, but it's all a little suspect...

For completeness sake, here is the onActivityResult from the activity creating the intent:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){     
        if(requestCode == BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                bt.connect(data);
                bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new OnDataReceivedListener(){
                    public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message){
                        try {
                            Log.i("SC", "Incoming data=" + IOUtils.toString(data));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            }
        }else if(requestCode == BluetoothState.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                bt.setupService();
                bt.startService(BluetoothState.DEVICE_OTHER);
            }else{
                // clearly pressed back or no devices selected
            }
        }
    }
```

And the Intent to start the activity in the first place:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceList.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
```

**EDIT** Requested:

```
 protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
    if (mBtAdapter != null) {
        mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    // Unregister broadcast listeners
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    this.finish();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to see the onPause and onDestroy methods of the devicelist activity?

Comment: Overriding `onBackPressed()` like you did is useless. The default implementation of `onBackPressed()` does exactly this: it calls `finish()`.

Comment: @DavidWasser - Yup, I know that. Was only really testing to see what I could do to get the activity to close. This was only for "what have I tried" - So it didn't look as though I was another "this doesn't work... I've done nothing myself" type of person ;)

Comment: @jvrodrigues - There is no onPause, but I've edited to include the onDestroy. Thanks :)

Comment: There is no need to have finish() in your onDestroyMethod, other than that i see nothing wrong with it. Could it be possible that you're creating more than 1 DeviceList activity?

Comment: Add logging to your `onCreate()`, `onResume()` and `onDestroy()` methods in `DeviceList` and see what is happening.